# JavaScript (WebStorm) global variables not recognized

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have a project in WebStorm 2018.2 with two JavaScript files:

- some-data.js, which contains a variable `someVar`
- main.js, which just executes `console.log(someVar);`

When I try to execute main.js, it gives me a reference error that `someVar` is not defined.

How do I fix this and make main.js import global variables from the rest of the files in the same project, and why does this not happen automatically?

Comment: do you run your main.js in browser (by including it in your HTML page), or with node.js? In the latter case, you should export your variable and require it in your main.js to make it work, as in the Node.js module system, each file is treated as a separate module; or, you need adding it to global scope explicitly by adding it to [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the variable that's defined is done so outside of a function.

In JavaScript, variables are either Local (defined and scoped within a method or function) or a Global Variable which is declared outside of a function.

Then make sure that some-data.js has been linked to your document, BEFORE your main.js.

It is not done so automatically to allow access variables at inopportune moments. For instance, so that you can name variables an identical name, inside different scopes.

Comment: Hi cmprogram, the only thing that some-data.js does is define a bunch of variables, so they are not scoped within a function. When you say that it has been linked to my document, what does that mean? Do I have to import it into main.js? (Sorry I am very new to programming).

Comment: @AfPho Don't worry about the additional questions. What you need to do is post your code so we can have a look at it. That's how it works on Stack Overflow. Without seeing the code it's all guesswork, whereas if it's posted I'll be able to provide you with an answer.
See : [How to Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)